# What to use to track work time? (Linux)

Tags: time-management, productivity, debian

KTimeTracker is being removed from KDE. Which (Gnome or KDE) program to use instead to track my working hours?

I have just a single time-counted project and want a robust and easy program included in Debian Linux.